# Which TransientFaultDetectionStrategy for communication with Azure IoTHub / cloud-to-device communication?

Tags: azure, iot, transient, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

We use the Transient Fault Handling Application Block to handle transient faults during Azure cloud-to-device communication. Therefore we define our own detection strategy which implements `ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy`, but don't know which exceptions can occur and which ones are transient.

The Enterprise Library defines some strategies, e.g. `CacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy` or `SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy`.

My questions:

- Does a predefined detection strategy for the communication with IoTHub via AMQP exist?
- If not - which exceptions can occur and which ones are transient?

Comment: I am looking to implement transient fault handling for device-to-cloud IoT Hub communication.  Did you find any more detail on extending the error detection strategy to detect transient faults?